# Find whether $f(x) = x + \cos (x)$ is one-one.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

> Find whether $f(x) = x + \cos x$ is one-one.

I tried finding $f'$ , $f'(x) = 1 - \sin x$ . But, how is this strictly increasing?

Following is the graph for $1 - \sin x$ that I plotted using wolfram.

[image: Graph for the function 1 - sinx]

Since the domain is not defined here, then how can we say it as **strictly increasing** ?

P.S : I'm aware of a duplicate (or almost similar) question to this one, but that doesn't answer my doubt. So, am posting my own one.

Comment: Since the derivative is always positive, the function is always increasing.

Comment: Ouch! Got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The derivative is strictly greater than $0$ except for a discrete set. Therefore $f$ is injective.

Look at the limit to minus and plus $\infty$ to get surjectivity by the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 3):

this may be too elaborate, but you can write $$x + \cos x = 1 + \int_0^x (1-\sin t)\, dt .$$ now, the integrand $1 - \sin t \ge 0$ and is zero only at $\pi/2 + 2k\pi$ isolated points, not in an interval of any postive length. that implies $x + \cos x$ is stricly increasing for all $x.$